# How can i use Create Chooser on button click inside a subclass of dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Using this code to share audio file through create chooser but not working...

public class ActionDialog extends Dialog {

```
static String sSongTitle="";
static String sSongPath = "";
static File fSongFile ;

public ActionDialog(final Context context, Message response) {
    super(context);

    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.after_save_action);

    setTitle(R.string.alert_title_success);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_share))
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri StringUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(sSongPath)); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, StringUri);
                Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, StringUri, context, null);
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "select any from the list:"));//getting error here as create method startActivity(Intent)

            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: can you put full code of subclass Dailog

Comment: @Brontok: am getting error as create method startActivity(Intent).

Comment: Where you declare your iShare variable ? It can be null. Code snippet like this out of context is hard to debug. What is your exact exception ? You should check the rest of the exception, there will be a clue why the activty can't start.

Comment: @Alex: sorry its intent.setType("audio/*")

Comment: Post your complete crash log...

Comment: Actually am getting compilation error am its showing create method startActivity(Intent)

Answer (score 0):

your Intent is intent not ishare 
Uri is stringUri but you mention ed as StringUri..
can you post entire code.. to see errors if any

Answer (score 0):

see this
code

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

{

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_share))
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri stringUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(""));
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);// intent for sharing
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringurl);
        sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringTitle);
        startActivity(sendIntent);// getting error
                                                            // as create
                                                            // method
                                                            // startActivity(Intent)
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: this code also give the same error. Leave it i got the solution.. i will create a class which extends activity and in the manisfest i will set theme as dialog and will get my things work. Thanks for your support